# How can I create an XSD for the following XML code?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to write an XSD for the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <PersonList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PersonList.xsd">
  <Person>
    <adhaarno>414356782345</adhaarno>
    <name>
        <firstname>Zeenath</firstname>
    </name>
    <age>28</age>
    <address>
        <doorno>33</doorno>
        <street>Raidu Street</street>
        <city>coimbatore</city>
        <pincode>641039</pincode>
    </address>
</Person>

<Person Category="seniorcitizen">
    <adhaarno>414356782345</adhaarno>
    <name>
        <firstname>Simon</firstname>
    </name>
    <age>75</age>
    <address>
        <doorno>7</doorno>
        <street>Raja Street</street>
        <city>Chennai</city>
        <pincode>600005</pincode>
    </address>
</Person>

<Person>
    <adhaarno>414356782345</adhaarno>
    <name>
        <lastname>Varma</lastname>
    </name>
    <age>25</age>
    <address>
        <doorno>25</doorno>
        <street>cox street</street>
        <city>Bangalore</city>
        <pincode>560025</pincode>
    </address>
</Person>
```

Here is my XSD code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<schema xlmns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<element name="PersonList">
    <complexType>
    <sequence>
    <element name="Person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <complexType>
        <attribute name="Category" type="string"/>
        <sequence>
        <element name="adhaarno"/>
        <element name="name">
            <complexType>
            <sequence>
            <element name="firstname"/>
            <element name="lastname"/>
            </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>
        <element name="age"/>
        <element name="address">
             <complexType>
             <sequence>
             <element name="doorno"/>
             <element name="street"/>
             <element name="city"/>
             <element name="pincode"/>
            </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>
         </sequence>
         </complexType>
     </element>
     </sequence>
     </complexType>
   </element>
   </schema>
```

However, I'm getting an error as follows:

```
Exception: s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'schema' must be from the
schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
```

I tried adding and then removing the prefix, to no avail. As far as I can tell, the namespace declaration(?) is correct. What could be causing this error?

Note: please excuse the formatting issues as I had some difficulty making the XML show up correctly when I added it in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: I'd typed xlmns instead of xmlns.

This line of code solved it:

```
<schema xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Admittedly not my brightest moment.